# Linking back to a source code file in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I am documenting a Python module in Sphinx. I have a source code file full of examples of the use of my module. I'd like to reference this file. It is too long to inline as continuous code. Is there a way to create a link to the full source file, formatted in a code-friendly way (i.e: literal or with line numbers)?

Comment: Read it as a file.. But i'm not sure why you want that, why don't you just provide running examples?

Comment: I have pulled out running examples, but some users like having a single compilable file to read. In a sense all I want to do is 'read it as a file' but if that file is buried deep in the filesystem (as site-packages often is, particularly on an Enthought distribution with virtual .

Comment: ... environments it is perceived as a usability hit. So I'd like a link to the file.

Comment: I had the same doubt but found something in Sphinx documentation. It is supported by standard Sphinx and actually has many more features then I was looking for, such as `diff`.
Added as answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41592881/5496529).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python 3 does this.  For example, [the argparse docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) link to the source code (near the top of the page, where it says "Source code").  You can see how they do it by looking at the [source for the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/_sources/library/argparse.txt) (linked from the first link, down at the bottom of the left had column).

I assume they're using standard Sphinx, but I am having a hard time finding `:source:` in their docs...

**Update**: the `:source:` role is  defined [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Doc/tools/extensions/pyspecific.py#l89).

Comment: please check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/21650878/246235 as that is the prevailed method

Comment: The "source for the docs" link is broken (404)

Answer (score 31):

If I get the question right, you want a link from your documentation to the original source file. You can do this by adding the `sphinx.ext.viewcode` extension to your conf file (under extensions entry). This will create a "source" link for every header of a class, method, function, etc. Clicking the link will open the original file highlighting the clicked item. More explanation [here](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/viewcode.html)

Comment: Note that you may need to add `.. module:: example` in your docs for the viewcode extension to find the source code for classes, methods, etc. and subsequently add the links to it in the output.

Comment: Note also there is now `spinx.ext.linkcode` ([link](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/linkcode.html)), which links to eg github instead of generating a syntax-highlighted source page.

Answer (score 21):

## literalinclude

```
.. literalinclude:: filename
```

From the [Sphinx (v1.5.1) documentation](http://web.archive.org/web/20170111135721/http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.5.1/markup/code.html#includes):

> Longer displays of verbatim text may be included by storing the example text in an external file containing only plain text. The file may be included using the literalinclude directive.

For example, to include the Python source file `example.py`, use:

```
.. literalinclude:: example.py
```

> The file name is usually relative to the current file’s path. However, if it is absolute (starting with /), it is relative to the top source directory.
>
> Tabs in the input are expanded if you give a tab-width option with the desired tab width.
>
> Like code-block, the directive supports the linenos flag option to switch on line numbers, the lineno-start option to select the first line number, the emphasize-lines option to emphasize particular lines, and a language option to select a language different from the current file’s standard language. Example with options:

```
.. literalinclude:: example.rb
   :language: ruby
   :emphasize-lines: 12,15-18
   :linenos:
```

> Include files are assumed to be encoded in the source_encoding. If the file has a different encoding, you can specify it with the encoding option:

```
.. literalinclude:: example.py
   :encoding: latin-1
```

> The directive also supports including only parts of the file. If it is a Python module, you can select a class, function or method to include using the pyobject option:

```
.. literalinclude:: example.py
   :pyobject: Timer.start
```

> This would only include the code lines belonging to the start() method in the Timer class within the file.
>
> Alternately, you can specify exactly which lines to include by giving a lines option:

```
.. literalinclude:: example.py
   :lines: 1,3,5-10,20-
```

> This includes the lines 1, 3, 5 to 10 and lines 20 to the last line.
>
> Another way to control which part of the file is included is to use the start-after and end-before options (or only one of them). If start-after is given as a string option, only lines that follow the first line containing that string are included. If end-before is given as a string option, only lines that precede the first lines containing that string are included.
>
> When specifying particular parts of a file to display, it can be useful to display exactly which lines are being presented. This can be done using the lineno-match option.
>
> You can prepend and/or append a line to the included code, using the prepend and append option, respectively. This is useful e.g. for highlighting PHP code that doesn’t include the  markers.
>
> If you want to show the diff of the code, you can specify the old file by giving a diff option:

```
.. literalinclude:: example.py
   :diff: example.py.orig
```

> This shows the diff between example.py and example.py.orig with unified diff format.

Comment: Is there any `pyobject` like object to display part of json object?

Comment: This is really nice! I'd be interested in displaying part of a C file, like for instance a funcion or just the header

Comment: If you want to include code from an online source file (e.g. a GitHub repo), you can use the remoteliteralinclude extension https://github.com/wpilibsuite/sphinxext-remoteliteralinclude